# Jest Unit Testing for Cron

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, cron

```html
//How to write Unit Test Case for the following Cron Job

index.js

import cron from 'node-cron'
export const cronJob = cron.schedule(pattern , async()=> {
  // do something
}

index.spec.js

import { cron } from 'node-cron';
import {cronJob} from '.'
jest.mock('node-cron', () => {
    return {
      schedule: jest.fn(),
    };
 });
 describe("Run Cron" , async()=> {
    await cronJob.start()
    await cronJob.destroy()
 }
```

This above code is not getting covered by TC
Do need a help thank you
The TC is covered 0% of the Code i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest testing the job function itself and not the scheduling, since that's where your "business logic" will live.
And that way you don't need to mock node-cron.

Answer (score 0):

You should **NOT** test the library itself, somebody has already done it for(most likely). But you **DO** need to test *your own code*, which is the function you pass to `cron.schedule` :)